# Get-ChildItem returns no items in script, but works from command line

Tags: powershell-4.0, get-childitem

I have a script that does some processing and then needs to delete files from a folder that haven't been modified for 10 days.

Firstly I get the date 10 days ago with:

```
$deleteDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)
```

I then try and get the file list with:

```
$deleteFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationPath | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $deleteDate }
```

However, this doesn't return any items (I output `$deleteFiles.Length`). If I run the exact same command, setting the variables first, from the powershell command line, it returns files.

I have tried adding the `-Force` parameter without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This destination folder contains only files or files are in subfolders ?

```
$del=Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationPath -recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -le $deleteDate) }
```

This will list file in all subfolders **-recurse** and only files **!$_.PsIsContainer**

This works for me:

```
$destinationPath = "c:\temp"
$deleteDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)
$del=Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationPath -recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -le $deleteDate) }
$del.length
```

And returns number of files.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for responding. The folder does only contain files, no subfolders or anything else. I tried your code, but again in my script it fails to return any files.

Comment: Are there any errors ? Is it a part of bigger script ? Try to run this as standalone script

Comment: I basically started the script from scratch, and used your example above instead, and it now works. Not sure what the exact issue was, but it works.